# nil value when populating views from struct model

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

I'm having trouble populating my views with data.
I made a struct called WeatherData.swift which holds my properties from some parsed JSON.

```
struct WeatherData {

  var currentTemp: Int?


  init( city: NSString) {

     //grab some JSON via NSURLSession & SwiftyJSON and assign in a closure

  self.currentTemp = json["currently"]["temperature"].int

  println("heres the current temp: \(self.currentTemp!)")

     //heres the current temp: 65
 }

}
```

Cool it prints fine!
But at the view controller when I'm trying to assign value to the UILabels:

```
func requestDataForCity() {

currentLocationData = WeatherData(city: savedCity)

var label = UILabel()
label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
label.text = "\(currentLocationData.currentTemp!)"

scrollView.addSubview(label)
}
```

I get nil for currentLocationData.currentTemp.
I thought maybe my code was assigning the currentTemp property to the label before it was initialized, so I used NSNotifcationCenter, but that also didn't work.
Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

https://github.com/yamski/weatherApp

Comment: We're going to need to see the full code.  If your println is in a closure it looks like you're assigning the value *after* init completes and `label.text` is assigned.  You'd even be mutating the struct meaning currentLocationData would never update to the right value.

Comment: Brian, You are right. I moved the println statement (from the data model) out of the closure and to the end of the init, and I get a nil. Can you further explain what I am doing wrong? I've added a link to my github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be that you are assigning the value in a closure *after* init completes. You don't show the closure in the code but I assume it looks something like this:

```
struct WeatherData {
    var currentTemp: Int?
    init( city: NSString) {
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://site/data"))
        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            self.currentTemp = readTheData(data)
            println("heres the current temp: \(self.currentTemp!)")
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

If you change `currentTemp` from a `var` to `let`, you'll get an error in the assignment: `Cannot assign 'currentTemp in 'self'`.  This will confirm that you are attempting to assign the value after `init` completes.  Similarly, if you were to move your println out of the closure you would see the app crash when trying to print nil.

One thing you could do, if you were looking for a synchronous API is block execution until completion:

```
struct WeatherData {
    var currentTemp: Int?
    init( city: NSString) {
        var semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://site/data"))
        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            self.currentTemp = readTheData(data)
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
        }).resume()
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    }
}
```

This approach has problems though:

- This will of course halt your UI every time you initialize a WeatherData on the main queue.
- It assumes that the NSURLSession has a different delegateQueue that the queue currently being run on.  If not it will deadlock.
- I haven't seen documentation explicitly stating that mutating operations inside `init` are guaranteed to affect the current instance.  It would be reasonable for Swift to have an entirely different copy of `self` in the closure.

A better approach is to move the work out of the struct, something with a signature like the following where completionHandler is called in the main queue:

```
func getWeatherForCity(city:NSString, completionHandler: ((WeatherData) -> Void)?)
```

WeatherData would have an init function that just takes the JSON data to extract the temperature:

```
struct WeatherData {
    let currentTemp: Int
    init(json:JSON) {
        currentTemp = json["currently"]["temperature"].int
    }
}
```

Then your UI code could look something like this:

```
func requestDataForCity() {
    getWeatherForCity(savedCity, completionHandler: { weather -> Void in 
        currentLocationData = weather

        var label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        label.text = "\(currentLocationData.currentTemp!)"
        scrollView.addSubview(label)
    })
}
```

Comment: I think I need to pick up a book on Cocoa patterns. I assumed since I println() the value in the closure, the value exists. It also surprised me that I'm actually assigning it after init completes when it's within the init function.

Comment: They can be hard to get your mind around at first. Whenever you create a closure and passing it to someone else (in this case NSURLSession) you are giving them a function to execute on their own timeline. Functions like `map` and `filter` are guaranteed to finish before the next line is called but network operations schedule the task and continue to the next line, calling the closure later when the request finishes.